# Running a Python CGI Web App off of a DVD

Tags: web-applications, python, deployment

I have run into a rather unique situation. I need to deploy a web application that uses Python CGI on a DVD. No software can be downloaded onto the computer of the user.

Does anyone have any ideas for how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Python is a script language and requires an interpreter to run. However, not all is lost. You can make an executable from a Python script. It is not clear if this works for CGI. I expect you will have to modify your code since CGIs are meant to run within a web environment. Here are a few links:

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm and http://www.logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script look good. But I would be remiss if I did not use a stackoverflow link so here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276296/how-to-make-others-use-my-python-script/17276712#17276712.

This link may help too: http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/

You are going to have to experiment around a bit. I did something similar years ago but with a different language taking HTML files and producing an active CD.

Comment: The web application makes AJAX calls to the python script. Could I do that if they are .exes?

Comment: I would think so. I cannot see why not. OF course I could be wrong. However, honestly speaking, my experience is not strong enough (recently) to get into the details with too much certainty. I did my active CD about 15 years ago. Where did the time go?? I do web CGI apps and data automation almost daily. I have not worked with AJAX except to determine how I will eventually use it in my own work (doing the big stuff before the little stuff). This was JavaScript, Java, and Perl. Not Python.